# Use AddError() inside an Apex Class

Tags: apex, validation, adderror

Is there any way that we can use addError() inside an apex class? I know it will work properly inside a trigger. But i would like to have a separate class for all validations instead writing them inside a trigger.

In the apex code it comes to the line and executes it but neither message will be displayed nor stop saving the record

Thanks,
Lahiru

Comment: No message and saving. What do you expecting from adderror then?

Comment: If the validation class is passed `Trigger.new`, then any `addError()` upon an sobject within `Trigger.new` will prevent the record from saving and generate an error message for the user. There is nothing about `addError()` that says it can only be coded in a trigger file

Comment: @cropredy Have you ever tried it from a batch? There are definitely contexts in which it cannot be used.

Comment: @AdrianLarson -- why wouldn't it work in batch?  If `execute(..)` does DML and that invokes a trigger that via its handler does `addError(...)`, a DML exception is thrown and batch `execute()` can catch it.  I would agree that `addError()` applied directly to the sobject in execute's `scope` argument wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

Apex classes have concept of Exception handling. This is similar to all other languages.

You can create an custom Exception class by extending the standard `Exception` class of the Apex.

You should go through following documentation: [An Introduction to Exception Handling](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling)

By implementing your own Exception class class whenever you want to interrupt the code simply throw exception as:

`throw new MyCustomException(' The Error Message');`

Simple Example:

```
try
{
     // Own exception class extending the standard Exception class.
     throw new MyException('something bad happened!');
} 
catch (MyException e)
{
     ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'my error msg');
     futureCreateErrorLog.createErrorRecord(e.getMessage());
}
```

If you want to let the error come directly to user interface, do not cover statements with `try-catch` (this is not recommended).